# android studio this file format is not supported

Tags: android

I work with Android Studio 1.5.1 and I build APK for my application.
    I obtain 2 files:
    app_debug.apk
    app-debug-unaligned.apk
    I transfer app-debug.apk on my tablette
    (HP Pro Slate 12,Lollipop 5.0)
    but "this file format is not supported".
    (I allow unknown sources)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you transfer APK to the tablet?

Comment: Check the developer options on you device. You may need to enable developer mode in order to install debug APK's.

Comment: I assume you followed the instructions at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews right?